# Any Office 365 REST API to sign out user of office 365?

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory

Is there any Office 365 REST API to sign out user of office 365 like Single sign out & by that way from azure active directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not an API per se, but you can just have the user browse to:

```
https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=<some_page_in_your_app>
```

Whatever value you put in the `post_logout_redirect_uri` is where Azure will redirect the browser after logout is complete.

Comment: Just a quick addendum-- if you need to log out a user without actually redirecting them around, you can always load this logout URL in a hidden iframe, like so:   

`<iframe src='https://login.windows.net/etc/etc/logout' style='display: none;'></iframe>`
That will log them out when whatever page in your app loads, if its an HTML page that is.